# Interbase 2009: complete removal?

Tags: interbase

Are there any tools for completely removing an Interbase 2009 SMP installation? I found an article describing how to remove IB6 (http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/28131), but I'm reluctant to delete anything in the registry according to a document which applies to another version of IB. Are there any equivalent descriptions for IB2009?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've run the uninstall and just want to clean up the registry. 
You could try [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/). select registry and scan for Issues.
If its the first time you've run it there will probably be many unused entries. 
If you're worried about changes then unselect all and just choose the ones related to IB.
Make sure you choose "Back up changes to registry"

Comment: Thanks 10bithacker. It doesn't seem to pop up with any loose interbase settings, though. I'm afraid I have to scan the registry "manually".

Answer (score 0):

Try [RevoInstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/). A very good program to cleanup register and files after an uninstall. Note that you should run this program directly when uninstalling. It calls the applications uninstall routines and the cleanup afterwards.